# Does Oracle open cursor in a simple select, update and delete?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'd like to know if a simple select, update or delete, for example:

```
select col1 from x;
```

or

```
update x set col1 = 10..
```

Open some cursor in Oracle. I know that when we are using pl/sql, oracle open implicit or explicit cursor when we use `select into`, `cursor curname is` or `for (select col1 from x) loop`.

My point is just understand more about some parameters like `open_cursors` or `session_cached_cursors`

Comment: Yes, these are also implicit cursors.

Answer (score 1):

Each and every `select` statement, DML statement, `execute immediate` PLSQL command and (top-level) anonymous PLSQL block opens a cursor internally. Of course, upon completion of the statement/command the cursor is immediately closed.

Detailed info can be inspected by tracing the event 10046.